# How do I save filter values in WPF toolkit datagrid "filter extension"?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using the code (VS2008) I found under the article "[Automatic WPF Toolkit DataGrid Filtering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx)", which works very well. It is implemented as a new "style" for a datagrid's header, NOT as an extension of the datagrid itself. My question is how can I save the values entered into those filter boxes, and later use them to re-enter those values?

If not possible as is, how would I go about modifying the source code (available from link above) to the filter (WPF newbie).

Thanks,

Enrico

Answer (score 2):

Don't have too much time to go deep into the code analysis, but you can find in code provided:

In `Generic.xaml` at `line 55` you will find this code:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
```

This code actually sets the template for the GridColumn. In the middle of *that* `XAML` you will find `DelayTextBox` type declaration. That is your key !

From `DelayTextBox` type's `OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)` begins the search.

Just another hint again:

In `DataGridColumnFilter.cs` you will find the following property:

```
public FilterData FilterCurrentData
 {
     get { return (FilterData)GetValue(FilterCurrentDataProperty); }
     set { SetValue(FilterCurrentDataProperty, value); }
 }
```

Put breakpoint to `get/set`, run the program and filter the columns. You will get a clear `callstack` vision, so can decide where you can pick up the actual value of the textbox, based on your app design.

**EDIT**

Look at `FilterData` type, it, I think, contains an information you need.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: No problem. I can't help myself sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can save them to the `UserSettings`. I would create an user entry for each filter entry and on load, populate the filter.